# Why does the string "¿" get translated to "Â¿" when calling .getBytes()

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

When writing the string "¿" out using

```
System.out.println(new String("¿".getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

Â¿ is written instead of just ¿.

WHY? And how do we fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to use UTF-16 to solve this:

```
new String("¿".getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
```

works just fine.  As long as the encoding given to the `getBytes()` method is the same as the encoding you pass to the String constructor, you should be fine!

Comment: That's exactly what I said, plus I linked to the API docs. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the Charset in the String constructor (see the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
System.out.println(new String("¿".getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"));
```

You need to specify the encoding both when converting the string to bytes and when converting the bytes back to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the system console isn't in UTF-8