# How to remove the Â character from a string in java?

Tags: java, string, utf-8, inputstream

I have the following string in which the `Â`  special character is coming in hidden. I want to remove only the `Â` from this string `~IQBAL~KARACHIÂ¦~~~~~~~~~~~`.

Here is a before and after image to show what I mean:

[image]

I've tried this code:

```
responseMessageUTF.replaceAll("\\P{InBasic_Latin}", "");
```

but this is also replacing the `¦` character. Is there any way to remove only the `Â` character and not the `¦` character?

Comment: What do you mean by "special character is coming in hidden"? Are you actually *expecting* to get that character at all, or is it possibly due to an encoding problem? What's wrong with just using `String.replace` and specifying the exact character?

Comment: Please check image i have attached here, showing notepad and internet explorer. this text is coming through streams.

Comment: Well that just looks like you're not reading it properly. You shouldn't be trying to mask that by replacing characters... (We still don't really have enough information to be sure - it doesn't help that we've no idea where the information is coming from or how you're converting it into a string.)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You have to use the right UTF:

**Code example:**

```
String blub = " ~KARACHIÂ¦~~~~~~";
System.out.println(blub);
System.out.println(blub.replaceAll(new String("Â".getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"), ""));
```

**Output:**

```
 ~KARACHIÂ¦~~~~~~
 ~KARACHI¦~~~~~~
```

See a description similiar to this problem here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176084/why-does-the-string-get-translated-to-%C3%82-when-calling-getbytes)

Comment: What's the point of `new String("Â".getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8")`? That's a very convoluted way of writing `"Â"`. Also, replaceAll() expects a regex. replace() is more appropriate.

Comment: I use this if i specify the charset for specific characters i have to parse. Its maybe not the easiest solution, but it works for me in my code.

Comment: Characters don't have a charset. A charset is used to transform characters to bytes and vice versa. No such transformation is needed here. You just want to remove characters from a String, which is a sequence of characters. `blub.replace("Â", "")` works just as fine.

Comment: You are right. your solution works well too and is much easier!

Comment: Given the question, I don't think this is the right approach - it does answer the question asked, but doesn't address the underlying problem of why the rogue character is there to start with. (And your conversion of the string into bytes and back again is utterly pointless.) The OP should work out what the data is *meant* to represent, and find out why it's not being read properly.

Answer (score 6):

I have a simple one liner code, it removes for most of the non-UTF-8 characters. I tested for your character as well i.e. Â.

```
        String myString = "~KARACHIÂ¦~~~~~~";
        String result = myString.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]","");
        System.out.println(result);
```

You can find complete code [here](https://gist.github.com/MaheshKapoor/10c854a4c258fa1070fc).
You may test that as well [here](https://ideone.com/3kKEpC).