# Replace non-UTF-8 character from String XML by space in java

Tags: java, regex, replace, utf-8

Checking this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31891207/808891), I'm able to replace the `â€™` character which is the apostrophe character `’` from my String XML by space:

```
String s = "<content>abcâ€™s house.</content>";     
s = s.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]"," ");
System.out.println(s);
```

The issue is that it produces 3 spaces: `abc   s house.`, I'd say because of `â€™` having 3 characters maybe? But I need for that character to be replaced by just one space: `abc s house.`

If I use below approach, it works while running from eclipse, but when I compile it to an executable jar, then it converts the `â€™` by the `’` and since the string doesn't have the `’` it doesn't work. (I'm able to see this behavior by decompiling the jar and see the code):

```
s = s.replace("â€™", " ");
```

Comment: replaceAll("â€™", " ") maybe?

Comment: @Mar-Z I already tried that, please see the updated post

Comment: `replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]+"," ")` ?! (just added a `+` to match once or more) || BTW be aware that `^\x00-\x7F` is more like non-ASCII instead on non-UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `+` quantifier:

```
    String s = "abcâ€™s house.";
    s = s.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]+"," ");
    System.out.println(s);
```

prints:

> abc s house.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below to remove Non-UTF-8 Characters and replace them with some value.

```
    if(fields!=null&&!("").equals(fields)) {
        return (fields.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\xFF]+"," ?"));
    }else {
        return fields;
    }
```